# WCF service failing to carry large array of from DAL to MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have WCF service which is returning data of 6500 rows of data list. When I am trying to retrieve that data from service it is throwing error like -
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://myservice.myDomain.com/Services/myTestService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details

I have tried to increase the time in configuration still the issue persists.

in Trace I am getting same like below :

Trace log it is showing the error like the same below :
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://myservice.myDomain.com/Services/myTestService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

stack Trace:

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is set up and start using the service trace viewer tool, this will allow you to drill further down into the specific call and find out exactly what the error is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Once you get this up and running you can run your code and then view the specific error you are getting, this will quite often be able to tell you what field or object is causing the error. The error you are getting in your debug is just a sign that something failed, you need to use a trace viewer to see what.

Without the actual error from the logging, it's hard to say exactly what is causing the error, however the most common cause is a lack of proper serialization on the object being returned by the service.

EDIT:

Looking at your stack trace it looks like you may have a cyclical reference somewhere in the object being returned, you'll need to add the IsReference=true flag to the offending objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference(v=vs.95).aspx

If you can post the code for the object(s) being returned I may be able to better point you at the issue.

EDIT 2: Also, if you can post the XML for the exception in the svclog file (copy the contents of the XML tabl in the Service trace viewer), that would shed further light also.